# Jquery how to subtract element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi guys so i am trying to make a nutrition label just like this : [Example](https://juicerecipes.com/build/)

Curretnly have my db all set up. trying to get it to work one thing at the moment and then can do it with the rest.

My db looks like:

```
ingName: ....
fat: ... 
carbs ... etc
```

The problem i am having right now is huge. I have been stuck on it for the last 3 days and no one seems to know whats wrong , I have a cross by ever div which is created so that the user can delete that ingredient he has added. So if they have:

```
Apple : 1g
Mango : 2g 
Melon: 3g 
Total : 6g
```

Lets say they dont want melon anymore then it should look like

```
Apple: 1g
Mango: 2g
Total: 3g
```

However i cant seem to get that to work. Every time i clock on the red cross it actually just makes the number in the label go blank.

My live site: 
http://diet.elementalbydesign.com/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/build.php

I cant stress enough how long i been stuck on this problem and how many people have tried to help me but yet no one has figured this out, again i am just at a wall here , really need someone to get me out :)

Again my live site to show you what is going on: My live site: 
http://diet.elementalbydesign.com/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/build.php

You can see that you can add all the elements etc, but when it comes to taking away , it goes into a shamble, if anyone does fix this problem will give them a cookie if i ever see u :) 
Thanks

Edit: This is the closets i have come, but it takes -1 on every time rather than the amount set in the database

```
                        $('.selectedStuff').on("click", 'span', function(){
                            var fat = parseInt($("#fat").html());
                            fat = fat - 1;
                            $("#fat").html(fat);
                            $(this).parent().remove();  
                        }); 
});
```

Comment: Ah I remember you with this website! I remember telling you to get the entire food list as a JSON object at the beginning on page load. It would have made all of this so much easier!!

Comment: @A.Sharma hi ye i tried but no idea how, but i am getting close, i just need to get the subtract to work and almost there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think Pekka is right, you should delete the whole div instead of the span. Otherwise, the yellow box stays on.

But the problem is that when you search for an item, you do

```
 echo "<script>$('#fat').html(".$total_fat.");</script>";
 echo $row['fat'];
```

So then in your JavaScript when you do

```
<span data-fat='"+data+"' data-itemfat='"+data+"'>
```

You actually have

```
<span data-fat="<script>$(" #fat').html(2);<="" script="">2' data-itemfat='<script>$('#fat').html(2);</script>2'&gt;X</span>
```

So try removing this line:

```
echo "<script>$('#fat').html(".$total_fat.");</script>";
```

---

When you write

```
var temp = 0; 
$('.result').val( data ); 
$('#fat').html(data);
temp = data;

temp = $("#fat").val(); 
temp = data; 
current_fat += data; 
$("#fat").val(current_fat);
$('#fat').html(current_fat);
```

The value is not properly added. Try fixing that first, with parseInt.
The original deletion actually seemed to work!

Suggestion: Replace all the above code block with:

```
$('#fat').text( parseInt( $('#fat').text( ) ) + parseInt( data ) )
```

Comment: Ah ok well that has got the numbers up and running :) but now its in decmails i think? or something weird, if you look at the site you can see, also want to thank you for the edit above :0 forgot about making it private :)

Comment: @Nevershow2016 I've edited my answer with something to try. Tell me if it works

Comment: Still nothing :( now i cant delete at all

Comment: @Nevershow2016 deletion isn't the problem, it seems. It's when you add an element.

Comment: Well you see when i took out echo "<script>$('#fat').html(".$total_fat.");</script>"; thats what caused the values not add , so if i put that back in it works , so i am not sure

Comment: This should be done in your JavaScript code, not PHP. See my new edit.

Comment: Sorry so this line u posted : $('#fat').text( parseInt( $('#fat').text( ) ) + parseInt( data ) ) what does this line replace?

Comment: i really dont know how to thank you enough for what u have just done :0 3 days i been stuck on this problem and just in pain , and you have just sroted it out for me, thank u thank u sosos much xxx

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of removing the clicked item

```
$(this).remove(); /* REMOVE THE DISPLAY OF REMOVED INGREDIENT */
```

you remove the parent div (which includes the red cross too) like:

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Would that help?